# How to generate a tor service onion address from the public key in java?

Tags: java, tor

I am trying to generate the onion address that is generated from a public key.

If the following line is added to the code in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671309/how-generate-a-valid-private-rsa-1024-key-for-a-tor-onion-service-using-java), just after *privateKeyEncoded*

```
String publicKeyEncoded = encoder.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
```

When I put the *privateKeyEncoded* into the */var/lib/tor/hidden_service/private_key*, save the *publicKeyEncoded* and start the tor service, a new onion address is created. I am trying to get the same onion address as the tor service and from one created from the *publicKeyEncoded*. Using this code

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

//base64 string from the public key created
String publicKeyTest = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCMnFkJTMZ2ZxnqLwCiB/EWHjsHbnC+sKEIrGbyOTYiTl3LygsekAX6LhgcllscLUFqSKlMRB3jRB0GAPrIc73E/hTnmWBtF8NT8DhZzl06LZ1BtNjfON1pHm87STMAayiSaXPmSOwIqOA89aJPcA9m4v4IhtjYSFXmCAsE4RqoAwIDAQAB";
//the onion address the tor service gives when the private key is used
String onionAddressTest = "qqkhrc4men3fiqyl";

byte[] publicKeyDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKeyTest);
MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] sha1hash = messageDigest.digest(publicKeyDecoded);
int numberOfCharacters = 10;
byte[] reducedHash = new byte[numberOfCharacters];
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCharacters; i++) {
    reducedHash[i] = sha1hash[i];
}
Base32 base32encoder = new Base32();
String onionAddress = base32encoder.encodeAsString(reducedHash).toLowerCase();
System.out.println(onionAddress);  // but this gives "7j3iz4of464hje2e"
```

I've tried using [spongycastle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) to  replicate my conversion but get the same answer. Which makes me think there's something wrong with how I generate the public key or there's something wrong in my initial conversion from base64.

Given the public key (*publicKeyTest*) how can you get the onion address (*onionAddressTest*) using java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://gist.github.com/DonnchaC/d6428881f451097f329e) and [this](http://blog.mmmonk.net/2012/09/how-to-calculate-onion-hostname-based.html) you need to **hash only the part starting at offset 22** of the X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo encoding used by Java which calls it 'X.509' and by OpenSSL which calls it 'PUBKEY'. I can't find any actual Tor doc on this, but I don't believe it can be accidental that this is exactly the beginning of the algorithm-dependent data in SPKI format for an RSA-1024 key:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i <49833260.b64
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 159 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   18:d=1  hl=3 l= 141 prim:  BIT STRING
# 18 +3 for DER tag+len +1 for unusedbitcount in BITSTRING = 22
# and the content beginning at 22 is:
$ openssl asn1parse -i -strparse 22 <49833260.b64
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 137 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :8C9C59094CC6766719EA2F00A207F11
61E3B076E70BEB0A108AC66F23936224E5DCBCA0B1E9005FA2E181C965B1C2D416A48A94C441DE34
41D0600FAC873BDC4FE14E799606D17C353F03859CE5D3A2D9D41B4D8DF38DD691E6F3B4933006B2
8926973E648EC08A8E03CF5A24F700F66E2FE0886D8D84855E6080B04E11AA803
  135:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
# which is (exactly) the RSAPublicKey structure from PKCS1
```

So to do this in Java you can just assume RSA-1024, or with BouncyCastle (and I assume, but haven't tested, spongycastle as well) you can actually parse the ASN.1 properly:

```
byte[] pubkeyder = Base64.decode("MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCMnFkJTMZ2ZxnqLwCiB/EWHjsHbnC+sKEIrGbyOTYiTl3LygsekAX6LhgcllscLUFqSKlMRB3jRB0GAPrIc73E/hTnmWBtF8NT8DhZzl06LZ1BtNjfON1pHm87STMAayiSaXPmSOwIqOA89aJPcA9m4v4IhtjYSFXmCAsE4RqoAwIDAQAB");
MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
// method 1
byte[] x1 = sha1.digest (Arrays.copyOfRange(pubkeyder, 22, pubkeyder.length));
System.out.println (new String(b32enc(Arrays.copyOf(x1,10))).toLowerCase());
// method 2
byte[] x2 = sha1.digest (SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pubkeyder).getPublicKeyData().getOctets());
System.out.println (new String(b32enc(Arrays.copyOf(x2,10))).toLowerCase());
-> 
qqkhrc4men3fiqyl
qqkhrc4men3fiqyl
```

Comment: Thank you. Spot on.