# InvalidKeySpecException: How do I extract a private key from a .der file?

Tags: java, rsa, private-key, der, pkcs#8

I have a private key file in the .der format. I'm trying to save this private key as a PrivateKey object (with Java) like this:

```
PrivateKey clientPrivKey = getPrivateKeyFromKeyFile("C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\Assignments\\Project\\VPN Project\\src\\client-private.der");
```

This is what the getPrivateKeyFromKeyFile method looks like:

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromKeyFile(String keyfile) throws Exception
    {
        Path path = Paths.get(keyfile);
        byte[] privKeyByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyByteArray);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec); 
        return myPrivKey;
    }
```

But when I try this, I keep getting InvalidKeySpecException because of this line of code:

```
PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
```

I'm not sure what's the issue here. I opened up the private key file and everything looks fine. It starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and ends with `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

And in case it's relevant, I created this private key using this OpenSSL command:

```
genrsa -out client-private.der 2048
```

Answer (score 2):

A file generated with

```
openssl genrsa -out <path to output-file> 2048
```

is actually not a `.der`-file, but a `.pem`-file (see e.g. [What are the differences between .pem, .cer and .der?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743415/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-cer-and-der/22743616)) and the data are not stored in the `PKCS8`-format, but in the `PKCS1`-format (see e.g. [PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 format for RSA private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958304/pkcs1-and-pkcs8-format-for-rsa-private-key)).
Keys in the `PKCS1`-format can not be processed directly using standard Java tools. For this, third-party libraries like BouncyCastle are necessary (see e.g. [Read RSA private key of format PKCS1 in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934846/read-rsa-private-key-of-format-pkcs1-in-java)).

Another possibility is to convert the `PKCS1`-formatted key into a `PKCS8`-formatted key with OpenSSL first (see e.g. [Load a RSA private key in Java (algid parse error, not a sequence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344125/load-a-rsa-private-key-in-java-algid-parse-error-not-a-sequence/29827944)):

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in <path to the input-pkcs1-pem-file> -out <path to the output-pkcs8-pem-file> -nocrypt
```

And then, after (programmatic) deletion of the Beginn-/End-line and after base64-decoding the private key can be generated (see e.g. [How to read .pem file to get private and public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787571/how-to-read-pem-file-to-get-private-and-public-key)) e.g. with

```
private static PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromKeyFile(String keyfile) throws Exception
{
    Path path = Paths.get(keyfile);
    byte[] privKeyByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    // added ----------------------------------------------------------------
    String privKeyString = new String(privKeyByteArray);
    privKeyString = privKeyString.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privKeyString = privKeyString.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    privKeyString = privKeyString.replace("\r\n", "");
    privKeyByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privKeyString);
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyByteArray);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey myPrivKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec); 
    return myPrivKey;
}
```